# Count li elements that are visible with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors, html-lists

Im counting my li elements with the following jQuery script:

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="relatedelements">
   <li style="display:none;" class="1">anything</li>
   <li style="display:none;" class="2">anything</li>
   <li style="display:none;" class="3">anything</li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery:**

```
    $(function() {
        var numrelated=$('.relatedelements > li').length;
        $('.num-relatedelements').html(numrelated); 
    });
```

--> The script returns: **3**

I change the `style="display: none"` property of some of the li elements when `$(document).ready` with jQuery, like: `$('.2').show();`

I now want to change the script in a way to count only the visible li elements with the following script (i just added :visible following the jQuery docs):

```
    $(function() {
        var numrelated=$('.relatedelements > li:visible').length;
        $('.num-relatedelements').html(numrelated); 
    });
```

--> The script returns: **nothing**

I have no clue why it doesn't work out - maybe anyone has any tip or idea?
Any help is much appreaciated. Thanks upfront!

Comment: **Thanks to all!**  

I think then, my problem is elsewhere in the code - However it is strange, as the couting script is working, but when I add `:visible` it crashes.  

However I'm now using a workaround. When I change the display:none css property I'm adding a class `.addClass("countme")` to the li elements that are visible.  

I'm now counting all li elements that have the class `li.countme`



Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

work fine for me

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.2').show();
    var numrelated=$('.relatedelements > li:visible').length;
    $('.num-relatedelements').html(numrelated); 
});​
```

JsFiddle Lind : http://jsfiddle.net/xuckF/1/

Answer (score 8):

Works fine here:

http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/FrPPr/ (1 visible)

http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/FrPPr/1/ (0 visible)

Now, using numbers as class names is **illegal**.  ([W3C Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters), bullet 2)  Class names must start with a letter.  Maybe doing manipulations with that is causing problems?

Other than that, I can only guess your problem is elsewhere.  Are you using the latest version of jQuery? (Although in my tests, it works all the way back to 1.3, and then it doesn't work at all)

Did you misspell "visible" in your actual code. (I've done this before)

Answer (score 2):

Element assumed as hidden if it or its parents consumes no space in document. CSS visibility isn't taken into account.

**View:**

```
<ul class="relatedelements">
   <li class="1 hidden">anything</li>
   <li class="2 hidden">anything</li>
   <li class="3 hidden">anything</li>
   <li class="4">anything</li>
    <li class="5">anything</li>
    <li class="6">anything</li>
    <li class="7 hidden">anything</li>
</ul>

<div class="num-relatedelements"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}​
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {  
   var numrelated= $('.relatedelements > li:not(.hidden)').length;
   alert(numrelated);
   $('.num-relatedelements').html(numrelated); 
});​
```

I've made a jsfiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/mgrcic/3BzKT/3/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. With the idea of the "hidden" class, I'm now adding a class "countme" to each element that I'm changing with .show() and it works fine!

Answer (score 1):

It works like that:

```
$(function() {
    var numrelated=$('.relatedelements > li:visible').length;
    $('.num-relatedelements').html(numrelated); 
});
```

You can see working example [there](http://jsfiddle.net/eFY8r/).

Answer (score 1):

Just take a look at this:
http://jsfiddle.net/vnMrQ/

Answer (score 1):

Yep, as everyone has already said, it works fine, even when you .show() the element doc ready:

http://jsfiddle.net/bKyt4/

Answer (score 0):

Your script returns nothing because all DIV's are hidden. It returns 1 when 1 is shown.

Comment: It will still return "0" when all are hidden.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this out and it seems to work i.e. I get a result of '1'.

```
$(function() {
    $('.2').show();

    var numrelated=$('.relatedelements > li:visible').length;
    $('.num-relatedelements').html(numrelated); 
});
```

NB: I don't think having numbers for the value of an attribute is valid markup

Comment: Thanks Peter - I think then, my problem is elsewhere - However it is strange, as the couting is working, but when I add :visible it crashes.

However I'm now using a workaround. When I change the display:none css property I'm adding a class '.addClass("countme")' to the li elements that are visible.

I'm now counting all li elements that have the class li.countme



Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In line one simply define a div or span or paragraph where you want to display count, and in second line the ul containing li

```
 $('.notify').html(
 $('#ul-notifications li').length);
```